# cmake convert to object file

Tags: c, cmake, arm, keil

I have a Keil project for an ARM target that I converted to a Makefile for a command line build system. I was also thinking of using cmake but I cannot find the right command/cmakey way to do the task. My Makefile converts a whole bunch of source files from different directories and creates object files out of them. Then the linker takes all these object files to make an executable taking in a bunch of flags and memory map files. So I can't just use the `add_executable` command. What can be the best way to do this in cmake?

EDIT:

So here is what the Makefile is trying to do(basically replicating the way Keil is building the project)

```
OBJECT_FILES=out/abc.o out/def.o out/xyz.o

all: binary.hex

binary.hex: binary.axf
           $(ELFTOHEX) $(FLAGS) binary.hex

out/binary.axf: $(OBJECT_FILES)
               ARMLINK $(MANY_FLAGS) $^ -o $@

out/abc.o: ../../../src/modules/abc.c
       ARMCC -o $@ $(FLAGS) $^ 
out/def.o: ../../../src/utilities/def.c
       ARMCC -o $@ $(FLAGS) $^ 
out/xyz.o: src/xyz.c
       ARMCC -o $@ $(FLAGS) $^
```

Comment: Linker flags can be set via [CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/variable/CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS.html) variable. Not sure what is a problem. Can you provide an example of what do you want to achieve? (E.g. in form of Makefile).

Comment: I added the Makefile that I am trying to convert for reference

Comment: As I said above you may set your *MANY_FLAGS* as *CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS* variable, so `binary.axf` will be produced from `.c` files with simple `add_executable()`. If you have many source files in different directories, you may follow approach suggested by @arrowd in his answer. For create `binary.hex` from `binary.axf` you may use custom command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`add_library` with `OBJECT` signature](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-buildsystem.7.html#object-libraries):

```
add_library(yourlib OBJECT sources)
```

and then link them into executable, for instance:

```
add_executable(yourexe $<TARGET_OBJECTS:yourlib>)
```